# Django HTML Template Cache

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have limited experience with Django but i am having an issue where I update the HTML Template file that serves an important view on our page and some users when they view the page do not get the updated view. Almost as if their device is caching the page. Now this page is not static and is dynamically generated on request. Now the part that I am changing is an embedded java script.

My question is is there a way that part of the page can be cached while others are not from within the same template?

Answer (score 3):

You cache fragments of a template using the [`{% cache %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) template tag:

```
{% load cache %} <-- at the top of the template

{% cache 500 sidebar %}
    .. sidebar ..
{% endcache %}
```

> It takes at least two arguments: the cache timeout, in seconds, and
>   the name to give the cache fragment.

Answer (score 3):

### TD;DR

HTML templates are compiled and **cached** in memory. Modifying the original HTML template files will not purge existing cached templates. One way to reset the cache is to restart the uwsgi/gunicorn service.

### How template cache works?

Considring the following Django settings (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/), `OPTIONS['loaders']` isn't specified and `OPTIONS['debug']` is `False` (defaults to the value of `DEBUG`).

```
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

[django.template.loaders.cached.Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) is then automatically enabled. The cached loader then stores the compiled `Template` in memory after unknown templates are first encountered. These compiled templates are stored in a dict named [`get_template_cache`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/template/loaders/cached.py) (though the variable name sounds like a method).

Answer (score 0):

for `css` and `js` files you can use `django-compressor` that can compress files and every time developer change `js` or `css` codes, just run `manage.py compress` on server and automatic generate new files that has uuid at end of files name and remove last files

for other part for other parts of page do as [doru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164282/6551200) said